# How can I push a long onto the stack using java bytecode?

Tags: java, bytecode

```
aload_0
    aload_0
    sipush 2377
    invokespecial game/engine/serverHook createGameServerSocket (I)Ljava/net/Socket;
```

Hi guys, I have this piece of code above. Can anyone tell me as to how I would load a long value onto the stack instead of the values that sipush supports? I think it supports 32768 +/-

I need a higher number than this, but I dont know how to go about using a long value, or anything bigger than this.

Any help is appreciated.

sipush 2377 < is the port of the socket, I need to change this.

Yes, I do need to use bytecode.

Comment: Any particular reason you need to use bytecode? Possibly a malicious reason? Or just some stolen and decompiled code?

Comment: `sipush` can only push a `short`. Is it meant to be used as a port number?

Comment: Nothing malicious, it's just a game that I'm trying to connect to using a different port. I've managed everything else but I can't change the port. @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes it's meant to be a port. But the port I need is out of range

Comment: Does `createGameServerSocket` expect a `short`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to push `long`? It won't pass bytecode verification during class loading.

Comment: If it expects a short then pushing a long will not work.

Comment: The port needed is 48960, and gives me an error if I use sipush 48960. @JesusRamos No the method itself requires an Integer. 48960 is a valid integer but how can I push that onto the stack

Comment: Java bytecode instructions are limited in size so the total instruction size cannot exceed a certain size. You must use multiple push instructions to push a full sized integer onto the stack.

Comment: @JesusRamos Ahh right, so I could sipush 24480 twice?

Comment: Yes and no. You need to push the bytes in the right order to make 48960. Not just pushing the same number twice (it won't add)

Comment: @JesusRamos Could you show me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Edit, what you actually want is an int, not a short. To do this, use the `ldc` or `ldc_w` instruction. (Ldc is only usable for constant pool indexes up to 255. When in doubt, use ldc_w, since it always works)

To push a constant long onto the stack, you need to use the `ldc2_w` instruction. However, since the function you're trying to call doesn't take a long, this won't help.

Example. This uses Krakatau assembler syntax. I beleive it works in Jasmin too.

```
aload_0
aload_0
ldc_w 2377
invokespecial game/engine/serverHook createGameServerSocket (I)Ljava/net/Socket;
```

Comment: That's pushing from the constant pool. I don't think the value he wants is anywhere in the constant pool.

Comment: @Jesus If he's using an assembler, the value will be added to the constant pool automatically.

Comment: You're right. I assumed he was editing the bytecode in some other way.